# Definition of Galois objects in a category

Tags: category-theory

I am using the reference by [Lenstra](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf). In page 41, section 3.14, he explains the definition of a Galois object in a category; but in doing this, he uses the claim (I think) that $F(A)$ is a finite set for $A$ a connected object, and $F$ the fundamental functor. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious under the technicalities, or if this was a corollary of a proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote the definition of a Galois category in the notes you refer to (section 3.1): "Let $C$ be a category and $F$ a covariant functor from $C$ to the category $sets$ of finite sets."

Comment: Ah right! My silly error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, $\mathbf{C}$ is supposed to be a Galois category, as stated in 3.11:

> **3.11 Proof of Theorem 3.5.** Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a Galois category with fundamental functor $F$. We begin with the proof of Theorem 3.5. Without loss of generality we assume that $\mathbf{C}$ is small (3.4).

This is also supported by the fact that the author appeals to the axioms of Galois category right after the sentence that this question is about.

> **3.14 Galois objects.**
> Let $A$ be connected. Then $\# \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{C}}(A) ≤ \# \mathrm{Mor}_{\mathbf{C}}(A, A) ≤ \# F(A)$, so $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{C}}(A)$ is finite. We call $A$ a Galois object if the quotient $A / \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{C}}(A)$ (axiom G2) is the
> terminal object $1$.
> […]

Going back to the definition of a Galois connection on page 33, we see that $F(A)$ is finite by definition.

> **3.1 Definition.**
> Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category and $F$ a covariant functor from $\mathbf{C}$ to the category $\mathbf{sets}$ of finite sets. We say that $\mathbf{C}$ is a *Galois category* with *fundamental functor* $F$ if the following
> six conditions are satisfied.
> […]